# Magento Products export session out while download 25K records

Tags: export, magento1.9.2.3, timeout

In my store 25K records available, when i try to download i am getting error like **Request is taking too long to respond**.
How can i solve this response error?

Comment: In php.ini file and increase the following values:
max_execution_time = 1200
memory_limit = 512

Comment: http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/10322-Increase-PHP-memory-limit

Comment: :) Ahaa Great ! Which steps you followed ?

Comment: @Aaditya  memory_limit = 512, this one.

Comment: Let me add the answer if the comment was helpful :) , which will helpful for the future readers.

Comment: @Aaditya sure...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91191/discussion-between-aaditya-and-zus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Increase PHP memory limit

---

**1. php.ini**

Locate your php.ini file by run phpinfo() function

```
memory_limit = 64M
```

**2. .htaccess**

Put this line in your first line of your .htaccess file

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

**3. PHP run time**

Maybe you hosting provider will accept you change ini information in run time, in this case you can add php code like this in first line of php bootstrap file

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

**[More reference](http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/10322-Increase-PHP-memory-limit)**